# Remove json object from jquery form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**Background:**

I'm working on a registration form in which a user can enter information about an unlimited number of people.  Each person is entered as a json object and is made up of the fields, as demonstrated below.

```
    addPerson: function() {
        //Create a json object for this person.


        var person = {
            id: $("#dialog").data("person"),
            fname: $("#dialog input[name=pfname]").attr("value"),
            lname: $("#dialog input[name=plname]").attr("value"),
            title: $("#dialog input[name=ptitle]").attr("value"),
            bio:   $("#dialog textarea[name=pbio]").attr("value"),
            photo: $("#dialog input[name=photo]").attr("value"),
            owner: $("#dialog input[name=owner]").prop("checked") ? $("input[name=owner]").attr('checked', true),
            percent: $("#dialog input[name=ppercent]").attr("value"),
            edu: $("#dialog textarea[name=pedu]").attr("value"),
            skills: $("#dialog textarea[name=pskills]").attr("value"),
            prof: $("#dialog textarea[name=pprof]").attr("value"),
            awards: $("#dialog textarea[name=pawards]").attr("value"),
            community: $("#dialog textarea[name=pcommunity]").attr("value"),
            years: $("#dialog input[name=pyears]").attr("value"),
            compensation: $("#dialog textarea[name=pcompensation]").attr("value"),
        }

        $(this).dialog("close");

        upsmart.people.finishAddPerson(person);
    },
```

Once their object is added, each person is then displayed on a grid with their profile picture and name see code below:

```
    finishAddPerson: function(person) {
        upsmart.people.people[person.id] = person;
        if($("#person"+person.id).length == 0) {
            box = $("<div class='person'></div>").attr("id","person"+person.id);
            box.data("person",person.id);
            box.insertBefore($("#new"));
        } else {
            box = $("#person"+person.id);
            box.html("");
        }

        box.append($("<img/>").attr("src",person.photo));
        box.append($("<div/>").attr("class","label").html(person.fname+" "+person.lname));
    }
```

**My question:** 
I would like to add a button that would allow a user to remove a person from this dataset.

I assume that this means I would be removing a json object, using a script like this:

```
delete data.result[this]
```

I'm just not sure how to apply it in a button for each element.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the finishAddPerson() function is storing the elements in an array, then you can use the slice [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array) function to remove an element from the array.

In order to trigger this action I would do something like this

```
<button class="remove-user-btn" data-person="person-id">Remove Foo User</button>
```

This can be created at the same time as your  element

```
$('.remove-user-btn').bind('click', function(e) {
    removePerson($(this).attr('data-person'));

    //Remove the containing div here as well, something like
    $(this).parent().remove()
});
```

Obviously the parent().remove() is dependent on the DOM structure and where you choose to place the button but you get the idea.

The `removePerson(personId)` would utilize the javascript `slice` function to remove that user from the in memory array.

I hope this helps.  I can put together a jsFiddle if you would like more examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm actually hoping not to have it reliant on user id, so that any user with access can add/remove any person in the dataset.  Is there a way to do it without the "your-user-id"?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I should have specified.  The "your-user-id" can be any identifying string.  I assumed that you would use the id parameter of the person object here.  I now see that I typed something wrong and will go fix that.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the tip.  I modified the function accordingly but my modifications seemed to crash the script.  To be more precise, adding the button wasn't the issue, but the remove-user-btn function seems to be the issue.   I've saved the modifications in [a .txt file here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11993667/people.txt)  If you had a couple more examples, I'd love to see them (I'm really new to all things javascript and am trying to catch up).  Thanks so much for giving me a hand here, I really appreciate it.