# ReferenceError while trying to remove json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

**Background:**

I'm working on a registration form in which a user can enter information about an unlimited number of people.  Each person is entered as a json object and is made up of the fields, as demonstrated below.

```
    addPerson: function() {
        //Create a json object for this person.


        var person = {
            id: $("#dialog").data("person"),
            fname: $("#dialog input[name=pfname]").attr("value"),
            lname: $("#dialog input[name=plname]").attr("value"),
            title: $("#dialog input[name=ptitle]").attr("value"),
            bio:   $("#dialog textarea[name=pbio]").attr("value"),
            photo: $("#dialog input[name=photo]").attr("value"),
            owner: $("#dialog input[name=owner]").prop("checked") ? $("input[name=owner]").attr('checked', true),
            percent: $("#dialog input[name=ppercent]").attr("value"),
            edu: $("#dialog textarea[name=pedu]").attr("value"),
            skills: $("#dialog textarea[name=pskills]").attr("value"),
            prof: $("#dialog textarea[name=pprof]").attr("value"),
            awards: $("#dialog textarea[name=pawards]").attr("value"),
            community: $("#dialog textarea[name=pcommunity]").attr("value"),
            years: $("#dialog input[name=pyears]").attr("value"),
            compensation: $("#dialog textarea[name=pcompensation]").attr("value"),
        }

        $(this).dialog("close");

        upsmart.people.finishAddPerson(person);
    },
```

Once their object is added, each person is then displayed on a grid with their profile picture and name see code below:

```
    finishAddPerson: function(person) {
        upsmart.people.people[person.id] = person;
        if($("#person"+person.id).length == 0) {
            box = $("<div class='person'></div>").attr("id","person"+person.id);
            box.data("person",person.id);
            box.insertBefore($("#new"));
        } else {
            box = $("#person"+person.id);
            box.html("");
        }

        box.append($("<img/>").attr("src",person.photo));
        box.append($("<div/>").attr("class","label").html(person.fname+" "+person.lname));
    }
```

**Where I'm at:**
In accordance with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18624097/2540204) by benashby, I've modified the finishAddPerson function as follows:

```
    finishAddPerson: function(person) {
        upsmart.people.people[person.id] = person;
        if($("#person"+person.id).length == 0) {
            box = $("<div class='person'></div>").attr("id","person"+person.id);
            box.data("person",person.id);
            box.insertBefore($("#new"));
        } else {
            box = $("#person"+person.id);
            box.html("");
        }

        box.append($("<img/>").attr("src",person.photo));
//added a delete button here
        box.append($("<button/>").attr("class","remove-user-btn"));
        box.append($("<div/>").attr("class","label").html(person.fname+" "+person.lname));
//delete function added here, using person.id to signify the profile to be removed
        $('.remove-user-btn').bind('click', function(e) {
            removePerson($(this).attr(person.id);

            //Remove the containing div here as well
            $(this).parent().remove()
        });
    }
```

**My Problem:**

The remove button fails when i click on it and gives me the following error in my console:

> ReferenceError: removePerson is not defined
>
> removePerson($(this).attr(person.id));

I suppose I should issue the disclaimer that I'm still slugging through teaching myself javascript and jquery so if the issue seems really simple... it probably is.  Still, any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.  Many thanks in advance!  :-)

Comment: Are you missing some relevant code above?  I don't see a function called `removePerson`.

Comment: @Archer Thanks for the response! Now that you mention it, it would appear removePerson really isn't defined as anything...::shakes head::  Looking back at the tip that I apparently followed without really thinking or understanding, the author suggested _"The removePerson(personId) would utilize the javascript `slice` function to remove that user from the in memory array."_  With that in mind (or using any other approach) how might I make removePerson something meaningful to fit my needs?  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, `upsmart.people.people` is an array that you add `people` to.  Is that correct?